# Удалённое управление компьютерами при помощи команд

Tags: сеть, удалённое-управление

Есть главный компьютер *(он только один)*, а также *n*  обычных компьютеров. Все компьютеры подключены к разному Wi-Fi. Нужно сделать так, чтобы с главного компьютера можно было отдавать на остальные компьютеры команды, сценарий которых прописан у них в запущенной программе.

Каким путём можно отправлять и принимать команды между главным компьютером и остальными пк?

Comment: Видят ли машины друг друга в сети? (Все в одной локальной сети или клиенты видят управляющею машину, выставленную в интернет, а сами за фаерволами, или еще как-то?) Какая операционная система?  Собираетесь отдавать одинаковые команды на всех клиентов, или нужен инструмент индивидуального управления? Что подразумевается под командами? (Выполнить произвольную команду командной строки, или правка системных настроек, или запустить вычислительное приложение, или запуск приложения с графическим интерфейсом?) Требуются ли административные права на клиенте?

Comment: В вопросе указано, что у всех ПК разная сеть. Команды одинаковые для всех компьютеров. Компьютеры находятся на Windows 10. Команда - обычный текст(string) с каким-то одним параметром. Это не системная команда, а собственная, которая обрабатывается не в консоли, а в самой программе. Насчёт прав администратора не знаю. У обычного пк(который считывает команду) программа лежит в автозапуске

Answer (score 1):

Для установки соединения, нужно чтобы машины друг друга видели: либо сервер видел всех клиентов, либо каждый клиент видел сервер. Проще - выставить сервер в интернет (т.к. он один).

Программа на клиенте периодически шлет запросы на сервер, о наличии новых команд. В общем случае это называется Remote Procedure Call. (Есть масса библиотек для решения этой задачи, с использованием разных протоколов передачи данных и с разными гарантиями на передачу данных по сети. В том числе, для разных языков программирования на клиенте и сервере, но, если язык реализации один, то выбор библиотек - шире.

Если будите использовать http-get запросы, в стиле [REST](https://habr.com/ru/articles/483202/), то. сервер не может знать получил ли клиент информацию успешно, даже если он ответил на запрос клиента и поэтому не может знать какие команды новые, а какие уже обработаны клиентом. Значит get-запрос должен включать либо порядковый номер, либо дату/время создания последней успешно выполненной команды, а ответ на этот запрос - должен, кроме самих команд, включать в себя номера (или время) команд. Клиент должен вести учет выполненных команд на своей стороне, и делать это персистентно (т.е. данные должны сохраниться при внезапной перезагрузке машины). Например, сохранять номер последней выполненной команды в отдельном файле на диске.

Comment: А можно, чтобы сделать реализацию проще, разместить на сервере текстовый(txt или конфиг) файл, в котором указана активная команда и её параметры, а пк будет через http-get считывать её и выполнять для неё заранее прописанный сценарий?